# how can I achieve Mathtype parentheses in overleaf?

Tags: amsmath

Here is my MWE (i would like to achieve parentheses A)

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    $\textbf{N}=\begin{pmatrix}
    -\dfrac{1}{2} & 0\\
        0 &     -\dfrac{1}{2} 
    \end{pmatrix}$------------%%%%%%the output is parentheses B
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't use `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (it is an obsolete setup using times-like fonts)  use `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}` if you want a Times Roman clone, but mathtype probably using something closer to the default tex fonts. But in general shape of `(` is like shape of `A` or `B`, you choose an entire font not the shape of each character separately.

Comment: Also, I'd use `\mathbf{N}` since `N` is a math variable.